# Repsonsive textbox and text

Tags: c#, uwp

The textbox in the ViewBox dosen't display and respond propperly. First of all it dosn't align to the left and second of all it have an gigantic text. Anyone that knows why and can help me to fix it? It should be as wide as the size of the window and have a normal fontsize for a textbox.

```
<Page
    x:Class="Labb3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Labb3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Name="Title" Text="Namlöst dokument" FontSize="22"></TextBlock>
            <CommandBar Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed">
                <AppBarButton Click="AppBarButton_Click" Name="NewFileButton" Icon="Add" Label="New File.."></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Click="AppBarButton_Click" Name="OpenFileButton" Icon="OpenFile" Label="Open File.."></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Click="AppBarButton_Click" Name="SaveFileButton" Icon="Save" Label="Save File.."></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Click="AppBarButton_Click" Name="SaveLocalButton" Icon="SaveLocal" Label="Spara Som..."></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Click="AppBarButton_Click" Name="ClearButton" Icon="Clear" Label="Clear..."></AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar>
        </Grid>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="1">
            <!--Tewxt Wrappingg="Wrap" och AcceptsReturn="True" gör att man kan skriva flera rader i rutan-->
            <TextBox FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Left"  BorderThickness="0"  Drop="myText_Drop_1" DragOver="myText_DragOver_1" AllowDrop="True" CanDrag="True" TextChanged="myText_TextChanged" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Name="myText" ></TextBox>
        </Viewbox>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!---->
            <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antaltecken" Text="Antal tecken: "></TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antalteckenmellanslag" Grid.Column="1" Text="Antal tecken med mellanslag: "></TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antalord" Grid.Column="2" Text="Antal ord: "></TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="3">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antalrader" Grid.Column="3" Text="Antal rader: "></TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this works as you expected, set the ColumnDefinition Width to “auto”, and set the Viewbox's Stretch property to "UniformToFill" and specify the font size.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!---->
    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" >
        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antaltecken" Text="Antal tecken: "></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="1" >
        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antalteckenmellanslag" Grid.Column="1" Text="Antal tecken med mellanslag: "></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antalord" Grid.Column="2" Text="Antal ord: "></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="3">
        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,20,10" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Antalrader" Grid.Column="3" Text="Antal rader: "></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no benefit to using Viewboxes (containing a TextBlock) in this case. They're specifically intended for "scaling and stretching" content; beyond what the content itself does; and that's what you're witnessing. You should specify what you expect the Viewboxes to do for you. I expect it won't be anything that the TextBlock can't provide itself (in this case).

And considering the number of property "values" you're duplicating, you should be using "Styles" to reduce the amount of code you're generating.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in a WinUI2 (UWP) application and made a few adjustments.

Just FYI the XAML code that is created for a WinUI2 (UWP) application can be almost fully reused in a WinUI3 application.

I removed the ViewBoxes from the second grid in the sample code. However, if it is a requirement for your project, take a look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox?view=winrt-22621) in order to adjust the properties.

The code sample I provided also shows the extraction of the style, in order to avoid code repetition. I've also cleaned up some unnecessary code, for instance:

`<RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>`

can be cleaned up as this:

`<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`

You can add this [Code Maid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid) extension to your Visual Studio to help you out.

[[Print of UWP (WinUI2) application]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC2g6.png)

The Grid code:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Foreground="Black"
                   Name="Title"
                   Text="Namlöst dokument"
                   FontSize="22"></TextBlock>
        <CommandBar Background="LightBlue"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed">
            <AppBarButton Name="NewFileButton"
                          Icon="Add"
                          Label="New File.."/>
            <AppBarButton Name="OpenFileButton"
                          Icon="OpenFile"
                          Label="Open File.."/>
            <AppBarButton Name="SaveFileButton"
                          Icon="Save"
                          Label="Save File.."/>
            <AppBarButton Name="SaveLocalButton"
                          Icon="SaveLocal"
                          Label="Spara Som..."/>
            <AppBarButton Name="ClearButton"
                          Icon="Clear"
                          Label="Clear..."/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Grid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill"
             Grid.Row="1">
        <!--Tewxt Wrappingg="Wrap" och AcceptsReturn="True" gör att man kan skriva flera rader i rutan-->
        <TextBox FontSize="20"
                 Foreground="Black"
                 TextAlignment="Left"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 AllowDrop="True"
                 CanDrag="True"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 Name="myText"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">

        <!--Extract the style for easier code maintenance - this code can later be transferred to a separate Resource Dictionary-->

        <Grid.Resources>

            <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle"
                   TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="10,10,20,10" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Left" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!---->
        <!--Reference the style as a Static Resource named TextBlockStyle -->

        <TextBlock Name="Antaltecken"
                   Text="Antal tecken: "
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
                   Name="Antalteckenmellanslag"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Antal tecken med mellanslag: " />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
                   Name="Antalord"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="Antal ord: " />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
                   Name="Antalrader"
                   Grid.Column="3"
                   Text="Antal rader: " />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Yeah kind of but we are using UWP as part of a c# cours in school so it must be in UWP